# How do I configure my Laravel app to receive mail through my DreamHost webmail?

Tags: laravel

This is the error I get whenever I attempt to send an email.

This is what I currently have on my .env file. This is still coming from my localhost btw.

I'm new to Laravel and I tried googling solutions but I still haven't found the correct solution. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

[.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgoVt.png) 
[mail_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr4OI.png) 
[config/mail.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6brYJ.png)

Comment: So users fill up a contact form and on form submit, send these details to my DreamHost webmail.

Comment: No, that's just an example. That's not the actual username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

command just deletes bootstrap/cache/config.php file, so just delete this file manually.

// Clear application cache using routing

```
 Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
     $exitCode = \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
     return 'Application cache cleared';
 });
```

Comment: I've done this command too, I run it everytime I change env file but still doesn't work.

Comment: replace webmail.dreamhost.com with
smtp.dreamhost.com

Comment: I don't use any of those.

Comment: have you tried smtp.dreamhost.com in .env  ?

Comment: This is now the error I get --> Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed. Please read: http://dhurl.org/20b D157"

Comment: MAIL_ENCRYPTION to tls and then try

Comment: MAIL_PORT=587  is also required for tls , for details https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215526937-Configuring-the-WP-Mail-SMTP-plugin

Comment: I'm still getting the error Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed. Please read: dhurl.org/20b D157"